# Python: unpack a zip to a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

I wrote an algorithm that takes a data frame and returns a table of aggregated results, and where the `ipywidgets` module is used. The user selects three variables and the results are updated and displayed automatically. The algorithm is as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import ipywidgets as widgets
import datetime
from ipywidgets import interactive
from IPython.display import display, Javascript

import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')

parquet_file = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/smaanan/sev.en_commodities/main/random_deals.parq'

df = pd.read_parquet(parquet_file, engine='auto')

df['executed_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['executed_date'], format = '%Y-%m-%d').dt.date
df['first_delivery_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['first_delivery_date'], format = '%Y-%m-%d').dt.date
df['last_delivery_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['last_delivery_date'], format = '%Y-%m-%d').dt.date
df['last_trading_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['last_trading_date'], format = '%Y-%m-%d').dt.date

books = pd.Categorical(df['book'])
books = books.categories

books_dropdown = widgets.Dropdown(
    options=books,
    value=books[0],
    description='Book:',
    disabled=False,
)

counterparty = pd.Categorical(df['counterparty'])
counterparty = counterparty.categories

counter_dropdown = widgets.Dropdown(
    options=counterparty,
    value=counterparty[0],
    description='Counterparty:',
    disabled=False,
)

date_picker = widgets.DatePicker(
    description='Pick a Date',
    disabled=False,
)
date_picker.add_class("start-date")

script = Javascript("\
                const query = '.start-date > input:first-of-type'; \
                document.querySelector(query).setAttribute('min', '2020-12-01'); \
                document.querySelector(query).setAttribute('max', '2025-01-01'); \
        ")

def split_tenor(row):
    start, year = row['new_window'].split(" ")
    if start == "Cal":
        months = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Q2", "Q3", "Q4"]
        year = int(year) + 1
    elif start == "Q1":
        months = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar"]
    elif start == "Q2":
        months = ["Apr", "May", "Jun"]
    elif start == "Q3":
        months = ["Jul", "Aug", "Sep"]
    elif start == "Q4":
        months = ["Oct", "Nov", "Dec"]
    else:
        return row['new_window'], row['volume']

    if start == "Cal":
        split_vol = [row['volume']/12] * 3 + [row['volume']/4] * 3
    else:
        split_vol = [row['volume']/len(months)] * len(months)
    
    return [f"{m} {year}" for m in months], split_vol

def ConvtoQuarter(tenor, delivery):
  if tenor == "quarter":
    if delivery[:3] in ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar']:
      return "Q1 "+delivery[-2:]
    elif delivery[:3] in ['Apr', 'May', 'Jun']:
      return "Q2 "+delivery[-2:]
    elif delivery[:3] in ['Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep']:
      return "Q3 " + delivery[-2:]
    elif delivery[:3] in ['Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']:
      return "Q4 " + delivery[-2:]
  else:
      return delivery

def filter_function(bookcode, cpartycode, datecode):
                
    filtered = df[(df['book'] == bookcode) & (df['counterparty'] == cpartycode)]
        
    filtered = filtered.drop(['deal_id','book','counterparty','strategy','commodity_code','trading_unit'], axis=1)
            
    filtered.loc[filtered['buy_sell'] == 'sell', 'volume'] = -filtered['volume']
        
    filtered['new_window'] = filtered.apply(lambda x: ConvtoQuarter(x['tenor'], x['delivery_window']), axis=1)
            
    split_1 = filtered[filtered['last_trading_date'] < datecode].copy()
    
    split_2 = filtered[filtered['last_trading_date'] >= datecode].copy()
        
    split_1["new_window"], split_1["new_volume"] = zip(*split_1[["volume", "new_window"]].apply(split_tenor, axis = 1))
            
    split_1 = split_1.explode(["new_window", "new_volume"])
    
    split_2['new_volume'] = split_2['volume']
        
    filtered = pd.concat([split_1, split_2], ignore_index=True)
            
    filtered = pd.pivot_table(filtered, values="new_volume", index=["new_window"], columns=["commodity_name"], aggfunc=np.sum)
    
    with report_output:
        report_output.clear_output()
        display(filtered.round(1))  
        
w = interactive(filter_function, bookcode=books_dropdown, cpartycode=counter_dropdown, datecode=date_picker) 

display(w)
report_output = widgets.Output()
display(report_output)
```

However, when I run the code it gives me the following error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last) File
~/sevencommodities/jupyterenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ipywidgets/widgets/interaction.py:257,
in interactive.update(self, *args)
    255     value = widget.get_interact_value()
    256     self.kwargs[widget._kwarg] = value
--> 257 self.result = self.f(**self.kwargs)
    258 show_inline_matplotlib_plots()
    259 if self.auto_display and self.result is not None:

Input In [1], in filter_function(bookcode, cpartycode, datecode)
     98 split_1 = filtered[filtered['last_trading_date'] < datecode].copy()
    100 split_2 = filtered[filtered['last_trading_date'] >= datecode].copy()
--> 102 split_1["new_window"], split_1["new_volume"] = zip(*split_1[["volume", "new_window"]].apply(split_tenor, axis = 1))
    104 split_1 = split_1.explode(["new_window", "new_volume"])
    106 split_2['new_volume'] = split_2['volume']

ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

Can someone please help me solve this issue and remove the error? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you tried printing the return value of `zip(*split_1[["volume", "new_window"]].apply(split_tenor, axis = 1))`?

Comment: @ac24 thank you for pointing this out to me, the error is in there, but I don't know how to fix it. I tried to change it into `split_1[['new_window', 'new_volume']] = split_1.apply(split_tenor, axis=1, result_type='expand')` but it gave an even bigger error.

Comment: You didn't print the return value. You're trying to unpack a zip directly to dataframes, I'm not sure this can be done

Comment: @ac24 it returned the same error `ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)`. The zip unpacking was suggested to me here, because I didn't know what to do otherwise. What do you suggest?